# Moved blog - galleries don't work

Tags: gallery, import

I moved my client's blog with nearly 800 posts from an ancient installation of WordPress to another host and a new version of WordPress. Now, several months later, we noticed that she had a few posts with gallery tags, and those tags are no longer working. I need to fix that, but I can't find any way to determine what images were used in the respective galleries. the posts just have something like this:

```
[gallery link="file" columns="4" orderby="ID"]
```

I do have a full export of the database (and all files) from the old site and looked through it, but can't find any info. However, it is quite possible I just don't know where to look.

The images do not show as attached to the specific posts in the media ui. For instance, one of her galleries was in a post where she picked a bunch of images from other posts.

Can anyone tell me how to find out what images were used in the galleries?

Answer (score 0):

Gallery can include either:

- specific images, in which case their IDs are explicitly listed in shortcode
- all images attached to the post, in which case shortcode doesn't specify that (as in your example)

So your description is a little contradictory - if images weren't attached to the post, then that example wouldn't have worked in first place.

Otherwise something in migration or update process might have disrupted IDs or parent/child properties, look into that.

Comment: Thanks Rarst.  I thought it was odd that the IDs weren't in the shortcode or attached, but figured I just didn't understand something.  Your help confirmed it.  

It was obvious that the shortcodes weren't originally in the gallery shortcode, so I worked a bit harder on the second option.  In case anyone with same problem happens along the post, here's how I solved it...

Comment: I searched the wp_posts table of the original blog's  database for entries with a post_type of 'attachment' and a post_parent of the id of the post the gallery was to display in.  This listed all the attached images for the post and I was able to get the image names and create a new gallery with those images.

Some images were not in WordPress, I'm not sure why.  But I was able to find them in the uploads folder of my backup.